# Where to put the number in organic nomenclature?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

Should one write 4-hydroxypentan-2-one or 4-hydroxy-2-pentanone?
It has been seen that both have been used frequently.

Comment: Check [PubChem](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/4-Hydroxypentan-2-one#section=Computed-Descriptors). As I understand it that site uses a computer program LexiChem for naming which is setup to follow all the current rules.

Answer (score 4):

The IUPAC recommendations on this matter have been changed.

According to the 1979 recommendations, the correct name was still 4-hydroxy-2-pentanone.

According to the [1993 recommendations](http://www.acdlabs.com/iupac/nomenclature/93/r93_42.htm), however, locants were placed immediately before the part of the name to which they relate. This rule is still included in the 2013 version. Therefore, the correct name is now **4-hydroxypentan-2-one.**